# Apply function to grouped variable using dplyr?

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

This [Learning R](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/) post applies a function to a column based on variable group:

The data looks like this:

```
 NAME, variable, value
 1   , GROUP1, 10
 2   , GROUP1, 20
 3   , GROUP2, 20
 4   , GROUP2, 30
```

I can use this function to rescale by variable:

```
nba.m <- ddply(nba.m, .(variable), transform, rescale = rescale(value))
```

How would I perform this same calculation using the dplyr package? I've tried:

```
nba.m <- nba.m %>%group_by(variable) %>% mutate(rescale=rescale(as.numeric(value)))
```

However this scales the entire "value" column without grouping by variable. Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Try `dplyr::mutate(rescale=`

Comment: Where does `rescale()` come from? It seems to work fine with scale: `nba.m %>%group_by(variable) %>% mutate(rescale=scale(as.numeric(value)))` What output do you get? Do you have both `dplyr` and `plyr` loaded? Did you load `plyr` first?

Comment: @MrFlick After I load `ggplot2`, some hadleyverse "scales" package is loaded which has a `rescale` function; I guess that's it. Must be, since `ggplot2` is in the title of the post the OP linked to

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the masking of objects in dplyr by plyr. This is why you should always call `library(dplyr)` after calling `library(plyr)`. Failing to do so should elicit this warning:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
You have loaded plyr after dplyr - this is likely to cause problems.
If you need functions from both plyr and dplyr, please load plyr first, then dplyr:
library(plyr); library(dplyr)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Attaching package: ‘plyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise, summarize
```

So you could run into similar problems with these other functions too. Solve it by attaching plyr before dplyr, or as @akrun points out: explicitly referring to the function from the package you want, in this case by prefixing with `dplyr::`.

Note that you can check the order of attached packages with `search()` (in this case I attached dplyr *after* plyr):

```
search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:dplyr"     "package:plyr"      "tools:rstudio"     "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices" "package:utils"    
 [9] "package:datasets"  "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"
```